# Combining Page Manager and Mini Panels

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-panels, drupal-ctools

I understand how I can use the Ctools Page Manager to override the system edit form for a specific content type. And I understand how I can use the Panels Dashboard to create a Mini Panel which can be embedded into a Panel Page. But I am not clear on how I can create a Mini Panel which includes an edit form (customized ala Page Manager) and which can be embedded into an existing Panel Page - which I'm assuming is possible.

Comment: Ask on the panels issue queue, they are very helpful. If not possible you can also mark it as a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Panels/Page Manager likely can not provide the level of detail you are looking for with the customization of the node edit form. You can not rearrange individual CCK fields. Panels is really just good at adding more in for node edit forms.

I like the module, Node Form Columns, http://drupal.org/project/nodeformcols, for theming a node edit form. Also with CSS using "float:right" you can tweak the form layout a little bit.